# Cascading Non-Inverting Amplifiers in LTSPICE

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice

I am trying to simulate in LTSPICE a circuit containing two op amps cascaded in series (so that individual gains will be multiplied) but for some reason the gain of the first stage is higher than the last stage, but when I remove the power pins of the last stage, the circuit behaves normally. What is happening?

I am trying to do a frequency sweep and have tried two different op amps (TL072, NE5532) but they both behave abnormally. I don't know what i am doing wrong.

I got my op amp spice models from TI.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no path to ground for the input bias current in the non-inverting input of the second op-amp.

Add a 51k resistor between the non-inverting input of the second op-amp and ground.

Comment: It worked! Thanks!.I cant believe I haven't tried that yet. Can you please explain why that's necessary even though the two op amps are tied to the same supply rails?

Comment: There is a small dc current called the input bias current into (or possibly out of) both inputs on op-amps. A circuit designer must always allow for this bias current to flow in order for the input stage of the op amp to function correctly. You had only a capacitor connected to the non-inverting input and because the input bias current is a dc signal it could not pass through the capacitor (capacitors block dc) and so the op amp's input stage could not function correctly. Adding the resistor enabled the input bias current to flow which enables the correct operation of the op amp's input stage.

Comment: @DaveL Give this a read:  https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/AN-937.pdf

Comment: Thanks, I always forget about those bias currents.